# ArraysIndexOutOfBounds exception in powermockito

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermock

I have following line in my unit class.

```
 @Reference
 private ConfigService configService;
```

So I tried to mock it as follows but when this line executes it gives ArraysIndexOutOfBounds Exception

```
whenNew(ConfigService.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(configService);


java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at org.powermock.api.mockito.internal.expectation.DefaultConstructorExpectationSetup.withAnyArguments(DefaultConstructorExpectationSetup.java:64)
    at com.google.core.servlets.forms.HmeServletTest.testDoPost(HmeServletTest.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:294)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:127)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:282)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:207)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:146)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:120)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:118)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:53)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

Comment: a little more code and stacktrace would make it clearer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use something like this:

```
whenNew(ConfigService.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(configService);
```

when you have to explicit call an object's constructor, not when you are using `Injection`.

Supposing `MyClass` contains the rows

```
@Resource
private ConfigService service;
```

Try this in your Junit:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
public class Test{

    @InjectMocks
    private MyClass myClass;

    @Mock
    private ConfigService service;

    @Before
    public void setUp(){
        myClass = new MyClass();
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this); // this row inits the mock of ConfiService 
                                            // and injects it in myClass

    }
}
```

Last but not least: if you didn't intend to use `PowerMockito` for anything else (static or private methods/fields/ other constructor), you can not use it at all.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and after a long investigation, I found out that I am using the same mock twice in a method. So I rest the mocks with **Mockito.reset()** between the two When() declarations and it fixed the issue.

Example:

```
when( mockedQuery.getSingleResult()).thenThrow(NoResultException.class);
//some code
Mockito.reset( mockedOracleQuery );
when(mockedQuery.getSingleResult()).thenReturn(stg);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the `.withArguments()` call.  I have not seen the `.withAnyArguments()` call before, and that might be what it is complaing about the array.  In your `.withArguments()` call you can use the mock `any` classes so you don't need to specify an exact object.

For example you could have a constructor normally take a `String`, and then custom class `X`: `whenNew(A.class).withArguments(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any(X.class)).thenReturn(aMock);`